# How to redirect to another page using jsoup and continue to print content in ListView?

Tags: java, android, html, android-listview, jsoup

At general I have website where the main content is the list of posts with text. So I parse every post in this block of HTML code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em">Some text</div>
```

For this I created this AsyncTask.

```
class NewPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Новые");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); 

            content = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");
            titleList.clear();

            for (Element contents : content) {
                if (!contents.text().contains("18+")) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

But I have some problem. All posts are not stored on one web page. You must click to link at the end of all posts for redirecting to another page with posts.

[image: Example]

And this block have this HTML code.

```
    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="paginator">

                <span class="pagina">1683</span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1682">1682</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1681">1681</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1680">1680</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1679">1679</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/3">3</a></span> " | "

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/2">2</a></span> " | " 

                <span class="pagina"><a href="/page/1">1</a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I go to another page, parse other posts and print them in ListView after previous posts? As a result I want have all posts of this website in one ListView. Can you show me how I should do it?

Comment: You will have to loop through all the pages. Here is an example of how you can get the link to the next page: `String url = doc.select("div.paginator span.pagina>a").first().attr("abs:href");`

Comment: Can you post the url website?

Comment: @Stephan http://killpls.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

#### Sample code

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Document doc;

    // I supposed URL variable is initialized like this: URL="killpls.me";
    try {
        do {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

            content = doc.select("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");
            titleList.clear();

            for (Element contents : content) {
                if (!contents.text().contains("18+")) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                }
            }

            Element anchor = doc.select( //
                "#stories > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span.pagina:not(:has(a)) + span > a" //
            ).first();
            if (anchor==null) {
                break;
            } else {
                doc = null;
                URL = anchor.absUrl("href"); 
            }
        } while(canContinue());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    return null;
}

private boolean canContinue() {
     // Implement custom logic here ...
     // Return true if additionnal posts should be downloaded false otherwise.
     return true;
}
```

#### Some details

The heart of the method lies on the following line:

```
Element anchor = doc.select( //
   "#stories > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span.pagina:not(:has(a)) + span > a" //
).first();
```

The `first()` method will return a non `null` reference as long as a next page exists. When the first page is reached, `first()` returns null and there is no more page to fetch.

```
#stories           /* Find an element with id `stories`*/
> div:nth-child(3) /* Select its third div child */
> div:nth-child(1) /* Select first div child of the previous div */
> div:nth-child(1) /* Select first div (DIV-a) child of the previous div */
> span.pagina:not(:has(a)) /* Select a span with class `pagina` without any anchor as child */
+ span /* Select closest span next to previous span and child of `DIV-a` */
> a    /* Here is the next page to fetch */
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution! But now I have another problem. All posts will have downloaded once (nearly 20000 posts). How can I parse and download them separately? For example, I want to download 10 posts, later I want to scroll down ListView with them and in the end of ListView I want begin to parse and download next 10 posts.

Comment: @Kostya You may create a method that will check if additional posts should be downloaded or not. See `canContinue()` in my update.